# Can't web scrape google using rvest

Tags: r, ubuntu, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

```
# I wanted to take every city in the column google it and get the state.
#for example it will search for newyork by adding it the search link with no separation
HQ<-df$headquarter_location
google_links<-paste("https://www.google.com/search?q=",HQ, sep = "")
g_result<- function(google_links){
google_page<- read_html(google_links)
state_country<- google_page%>% 
html_nodes(".E75vKf span") %>% html_text()

} 
# Then i would use the sapply function to organize the results in a new column
```

but for some reason that didn't work on google , bing , duckduckgo ,nor any of the common search engines. it did work with similar things on websites like imdb or some pages of Wikipedia.

I've tried using Rselenium but it always gives me an error like:

```
BEGIN: Download 
#multiple time
```

and i cant find solutions except for windows and i use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I am not an American but I doubt the best way of getting the state of an American city is to google the city's name. I would rather find a website listing cities and scrape it. [CityTownInfo.com](https://www.citytowninfo.com/places) seems pretty complete, a cursory reading lists Platinum, Alaska, pop 13.

Comment: me neither, that's why i want a reliable way of scraping multiple cities to categorize them by state.